# Fetch fixed rows with filters in Hbase using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

In my application, I need to fetch the data from Hbase and I need to apply filters on that data and I need to have a limit on the number of records to be fetched. Below is the code that I have written:

```
ResultScanner scanner = null;
HTable table = null;
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", hbaseServer);
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", hbasePort);
        FilterList list = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
        table = new HTable(config, "TableName");
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("ColumnName"),
                    Bytes.toBytes("ColumnName"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                    new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf("FilterValue"))));
            SingleColumnValueFilter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("ColumnName2"),
                    Bytes.toBytes("ColumnName2"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                    new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf("FilterValue2"))));
            list.addFilter(filter);
            list.addFilter(filter1);
 Scan scan = new Scan();
 scan.setFilter(list);
 scan.setFilter(new PageFilter(10));
 scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

The filters are working perfectly fine but I am getting the complete dataset. 
scan.setFilter(new PageFilter(10)) is not working. I need to pull only top 10 records that are matching the filters provided. I have also tried:

```
scan.setMaxResultSize(10);
scan.setMaxResultsPerColumnFamily(10);
```

But none of these are also working. What could be the issue with the above code?

Comment: `setMaxResultSize` doesn't do what you think - it sets the maximum result size in bytes. https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#getMaxResultSize--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copied the code correctly, you rewrite your first filter:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(list);
scan.setFilter(new PageFilter(10));  <-- changes FilterList to PageFilter
```

Seems that you wanted to do

```
list.addFilter(new PageFilter(10));
```